# Get count of each unique word across all strings in an array column

Tags: php, arrays, unique, word-count, array-column

I'd like to get a unique word count including all strings in an array column.

Input:

```
[
    [
        "Query" => "hehe haha hihi",
        "Merry" => "1.11"
    ],
    [
         "Query" => "hehe hoho hrooo",
         "Merry" => "1.12"
    ]
]
```

I want to get the values of the "Query" key of EACH array (not just first which I'm getting) and explode it by space " " so that I can match the Query value that repeats.

Desired result:

```
[
    'hehe' => 2,
    'haha' => 1,
    'hihi' => 1,
    'hrooo' => 1
]
```

So what I want to achieve is to compare the "Query" key in each nested array so that I can find those that match and then count them with array_count_values() to achieve the above result.

But when I loop the array I only get the first nested array result, like this:

```
[
    'hehe' => 1,
    'haha' => 1,
    'hihi' => 1
]
```

and not from all nested arrays.

Let's say that the array is in variable $data, and what I did so far is:

```
foreach($data as $k => $v)
{
    // now the $k is 0, and $v is the whole first object 
    // (with both Query and Merry keys, if I foreach again
  foreach($v as $key => $value)
  {
      // now the $key is Query, and $value is "hehe haha hihi" which is great! 
      // But I want the same result for ALL nested arrays, not just this first. 
  }
}
```

How to achive that and where am I losing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the sentence to an array of words, merge them all and then count:

```
$wordArrays = array_map(function ($v) { return explode(" ", $v["Query"]; }, $array); //Get the words from the sentence
$combinedWordArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $wordArrays); //Flatten the array
$result = array_count_values($combinedWordArray); //Count
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f234715df744fe93d8cf5238f90e37fb65ca7c4

Comment: That's it mate! mapping! Thanks a lot :) Now I have to sort them descending (most to least repeated) and that's it

Comment: @hrca02 `arsort($result)` should be enough for that

Answer (score 0):

1. Isolate the Query column values.
2. Implode them with spaces to form a single string
3. Explode on spaces
4. Count words

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tfBYA))

```
var_export(
    array_count_values(
        explode(
            ' ',
            implode(
                ' ',
                array_column($array, 'Query')
            )
        )
    )
);
```